# How can we identify the symmetry of the molecule from its IC table?

Tags: molecular-modeling, symmetry, algorithms

We are given the IC table for benzene in CHARMM format, which can be written as follows:

```
C1 C2 C3 C4 1.42 120 0.000 120.00 1.42
C2 C3 C4 C5 1.42 120 0.000 120.00 1.42
C3 C4 C5 C6 1.42 120 0.000 120.00 1.42
H1 C1 C2 H2 1.00 120 0.000 120.00 1.00
H3 C3 C4 H4 1.00 120 0.000 120.00 1.00
H5 C5 C6 H6 1.00 120 0.000 120.00 1.00
```

This is for the case where the molecule has $D_{6h}$ symmetry.

Assume that we do not know what the point group of the molecule is and would like to have an algorithm to identify the point group of the molecule. I know the existence of this flowchart which shows the procedure to identify the point group of any molecule. However, this is something that is more intuitive to a human being and not for a computer. In that case, how can we then identify the point group based on the information from the IC table.

I had previously asked this [question](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/questions/10160/locating-symmetry-equivalent-atoms-from-distance-matrix) where I was instructed to use libmysm package to identify the molecular point group. However, here I am looking for a general algorithm that can do this from z-matrices.

[image]

Comment: +1, I am not sure whether it is just me, but I can't see the attached figure in your question.

Comment: Now even I can't see it. I'll edit the question